# My Google Admob ads not showing for my android game

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-play, admob, googleads-mobile-unity

My game has Unity Ads and Google AdMob. I used Google AdMob for a support button. Button shows rewarded ad, with no prizes. Because this is a support button. Anyway, my ads is not showing. I'm trying to solve this problem. I think i did everything true. I published my game. In my other game Google Ads is showing. Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

First, This is against AdMob's [Policies for ads that offer rewards](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/7313578?hl=en)

> Publishers may not encourage users to engage with rewarded ads using phrases that indicate the ad engagement will help the publisher directly, such as **“support us”** or similar language.

I STRONGLY recommend removing the support button because AdMob will find it and give you a violation strike.

Second, regarding your problem I think you are not preloading the ad.